# XtraTreeList ExporttoXML

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I tried xtraTreeList's exporttoXML property. But the generated xml does not contain any information of the node like ID or is Chcked etc and just the name and parentID. Is there any other export property which will give all the information ?

Answer (score 0):

> [TreeList.ExportToXml(String) Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_ExportToXmltopic1776) exports the tree list's data
> to the specified file as XML not the layout. You can use
> [TreeList.SaveLayoutToXml(String) Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SaveLayoutToXmltopic1795) to save the layout and
> restore it by using [TreeList.RestoreLayoutFromXml(String) Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_RestoreLayoutFromXmltopic1789).

Code snippet:

```
string fileName = "c:\\TreeListLayout.xml";
treeList1.SaveLayoutToXml(fileName);
treeList2.DataSource = treeList1.DataSource;
treeList2.RestoreLayoutFromXml(fileName);
```

Go Through DevExpress Example [How to preserve the expanded state of TreeList nodes when refreshing data](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E864.aspx) and the following reference links.

Ref:

[How to load and save the layout of a TreeList by code](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q333550.aspx)
[SearchResult](http://search.devexpress.com/default.aspx?q=save%20list%20to%20xml&p=T4%7CP1%7C58&page=2)

Hope this help..

Comment: I am aware of both the properties ExportToXml and SaveLayoutToXml. But i need to capture the information that which nodes are checked and while re-building the tree, need to apply checks based on xml from old tree. Unfortunately none of the above properties will give me the info about checked items and will have to use some workaround  to apply checks.

Comment: refer the example and check whether it is working for you or not.